# AddIn.Object returns null on certain machines

Tags: excel, vsto

I have:

1. A VSTO Excel Add-In;
2. An override object `RequestComAddInAutomationService()` which returns an instance of a class which is annotated as
   `[ComVisible(true)]`
   `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]`
   and implements an interface which is annotated
   `[ComVisible(true)]`
   `[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]`
3. Accessing the `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.COMAddIns.Item("MyAddinName").Object` from the addin process I am able to get the above mentioned class;
4. Accessing `Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application").COMAddIns.Item("MyAddinName").Object` in c# code which is called (Excel DNA) from a VBA macro I usually am able to get the above mentioned class. But on certain machines this reference is null.

Anyone knows what could be the reason?

Comment: What are the differences between the machines? What's different about the machines with the null references?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the COMAddins are available in Developer => Com Add-Ins button in both the machine first.

Answer (score 0):

In your Excel-DNA add-in, you should always get the right Application object with a call to `ExcelDnaUtil.Application`. Otherwise, with bad code like `GetActiveObject(...)` you might get another Excel instance running on that machine.